# Using C# System.Timers.Timer on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, timer, signalr

I'm using a static **ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Timer>** for mapping some live games. Basically for every game, when the game starts, I'm adding a new timer in the dictionary. The timer role is to handle every game round finished event ( when user didn't move during the round time - 30 seconds - the timer is called and it will execute a move for that user). After an amount of time, when the game will be finished, the timer is extracted from the dictionary and stopped. Everything works as expected on the local environment, but on the Azure App Service, timer doesn't work. I don't know exactly if this is the best approach for these games. I'm using .NET Core 3.1 with Signal R for the Web API, and Angular 8 for the client. Do the timers work on Azure or should I use Azure Functions for this kind of purposes?

Comment: have the same issue, did you find any solution?